# Applescript to execute code based on results of a terminal command

Tags: terminal, applescript

I'm trying to make a script that lets a user copy many files out of one directory into various other locations based on a spreadsheet. The user won't have the exact filenames, so the script needs to copy everything that matches a criteria. I figured the terminal's `ls *[criteria]*` is the best way to determine if there are any matches.

The problem happens when I try to use the results of the terminal command. Here's the error:
`"Can’t make «class ttab» 1 of window id 24015 of application \"Terminal\" into type list or string." number -1700 from «class ttab» 1 of window id 24015 to list or string`

Here's the full code:

```
set theSheetAlias to choose file with prompt "Please select the spreadsheet." of type {"public.spreadsheet"}
set theSourceAlias to choose folder with prompt "Please select where to look for photos."
set theSourcePath to quoted form of POSIX path of the theSourceAlias

tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("cd " & theSourcePath)
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open alias theSheetAlias
    set theSheet to active sheet
    
    -- Loop through each row and move the file to the specified location
    repeat with i from 2 to count of rows of theSheet's used range
        set theStyle to the value of cell 2 of row i of theSheet
        tell application "Terminal"
            set terminalSearch to (do script ("ls *" & theStyle & "*") in currentTab)
            if terminalSearch starts with "zsh: no matches" then
                -- execute some code
            else
                -- execute some other code
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: `do script` only returns the tab the command was executed in, so the comparison with `terminalSearch` is failing.

Comment: right, so how do I extract something useful out of the terminal tab?

Comment: The Terminal window/tab has a contents property, so you would need to look at that to determine the results you want.

Comment: I've found that when using the tab's `contents` property, I get the same error as if I'm trying to do a text comparison with the entire tab object. I am able to do a comparion with the tab's `history` property, but i'm nervous about that since the history could potentially become extremely long. Terminal's dictionary shows both contents and history as r/o text properties, so why are they behaving differently?

Comment: Why are you even using the Terminal? Use `do shell script`.

Comment: As to your previous comment… probably because the Terminal is a mess from an applescript perspective. Just a guess, though. That said, you could likely get the result you want if you put in an intermediary line of `set p1 to properties of terminalSearch` and then `contents of p1`.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about the `contents` term, so depending on how much data you are wanting to get you can use `history`, or get `contents` of the properties of the tab.  You will also need to delay a little for contents to appear in the window.  Yes, it is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't need to involve terminal at all. Instead of opening terminal, changing to the directory I want, then running a command, I found I can wrap all of that into a single command and run it directly as a shell script:

```
do shell script ("ls " & theSourcePath & "*" & theStyle & "*")
```

and the best part is that it returns the result of the command, which is exactly what I wanted:

```
set searchResult to the result
```

but if the `ls` doesn't turn up any results, it throws an error. It's better to do the error checking in the shell than a try/catch block in the applescript, so here's the final shell script line:

```
do shell script ("ls " & theSourcePath & "*" & theStyle & "* || echo \"error\"")
```

here's what it all looks like now. Still a lot of functions to add, but the original problem I was having is completely solved

```
set theSheetAlias to choose file with prompt "Please select the spreadsheet." of type {"public.spreadsheet"}
set theSourceAlias to choose folder with prompt "Please select where to look for photos."
set theSourcePath to quoted form of POSIX path of the theSourceAlias


tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open alias theSheetAlias
    set theSheet to active sheet
    
    -- Loop through each row and search for any files matching the values in column B
    repeat with i from 2 to count of rows of theSheet's used range
        set theStyle to the value of cell 2 of row i of theSheet
        
        do shell script ("ls " & theSourcePath & "*" & theStyle & "* || echo \"error\"")
        set searchResult to the result
        set resultLines to every paragraph in searchResult
        
        if searchResult is equal to "error" then
            set value of cell 4 of row i of theSheet to "not found"
        else
            set value of cell 4 of row i of theSheet to ((length of resultLines as text) & " files found")
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```